# AVCaptureStillImageOutput on pageView

Tags: ios, avfoundation, uipageviewcontroller

I am using AVFoundation in IOS and so far I have made a custom camera and I am able to click the images and the output(which is a image) uses the class AVCaptureStillImageOutput.

Now everytime I click an image,I save it in an array.Now I am showing all these images in a pageView.The only problem now is that I am taking image in portrait mode but they appear in landscape mode on pageView.

Since I am working on AVFoundation for the first time,so I don't understand the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a category for UIImage which returns the image

```
    - (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

// No-op if the orientation is already correct
if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

// We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
// We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
}
```

Just make a category and ad this method in that category.Then call this 'fixOrientation' method.It returns an UIImage and that is exactly the image that is needed.